# Visual Studio unable to rebuild the executable, as its protected from writing

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing a very annoying problem lately.
After building my source code for few times and getting runtime error. My computer seems to protect the executable from writing, as the visual studio report.

```
Severity Code   Description 
Error   LNK1168 cannot open C:\Users\Gedalia\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe for writing
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was solved by closing the program which was running secretly in the background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this file is executed. Probably process hung. Press `Ctrl+Alt+Esc` go to processes list, find it and force close before building.